# Chain rule in a Hilbert space.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, hilbert-spaces, chain-rule, frechet-derivative

Let $F:H\to \mathbb{R}$ be some functional on a Hilbert space $H$. Denote its Frechet derivative at $h\in H$ as $\frac{\delta F}{\delta h}(h)$. Suppose $h_t$ is a curve in $H$ i.e $$h_\cdot : \mathbb{R}\to H,~~~~ t\mapsto h_t$$

how do I use the chain rule in this case to show that

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(h_t)=\Big\langle \frac{\delta F}{\delta h}(h_t) , \partial_t h_t \Big\rangle ~~~~~?$$

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're missing; you say that you want to use the chain rule, and then you write down what is (to my eyes) the chain rule itself (specialized to the case of maps $\mathbb R \to H \to \mathbb R$).  So it seems that you want to use the chain rule to show the chain rule!  Perhaps @janmarqz's answer will help clarify things for you; but otherwise, it would probably help if you write down what exactly what ‘the chain rule’, as you understand it, says, so that we can help you link it to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using the composition
$$\mathbb R\stackrel h\to H \stackrel F\to\mathbb R$$
and the point of view of
$$\mathbb R\stackrel{F\cdot h}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$$
it means that $(F\circ h)'=F'(h)\cdot h'$ among the derivatives.