# Special case of chain rule

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, chain-rule

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space, $I:H \to \mathbb{R}$ is a functional and $\eta_t:\mathbb{R} \to H$.

I want to understand why

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{d t} I\left(\eta_t\right)=\left(I^\prime\left[\eta_t\right],\frac{d}{d t}  (\eta_t)\right),
\end{equation*}

where $(.,.)$ is the inner product of $H$. I know that the formula is true when $H$ is a finite dimensional space (for example, $\mathbb{R}^n$), for then you can write coordinates $x_1,\dots, x_n$ and with the chain rule the inner product naturally appears. My question is how to show this formula is true when $H$ is an arbitrary Hilbert space.

Comment: A similar question was posted in the past about the same topic it seems: [Chain rule in a Hilbert space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4565815)

Comment: What is your definition of $I'(x)$ for $x \in H$? If it is what I think it is, then it should be straightforward from the chain rule for Fréchet derivatives in Banach spaces.

Comment: @BrunoB $I\prime (x)$ is the Fréchet derivative of $I$, but I‘m not very familiar on how the chain rule for Fréchet derivatives works. I have also seen the linked post, but didn‘t understand the answer.

Comment: Usually the Fréchet derivative at a point is a bounded linear functional, but here it is clearly meant to designate a vector of $H$. What that means is that $I'(x)$ should be the vector $v$ from the Riesz representation theorem, aka the unique vector $v \in H$ such that, if we denote by $dI(x)$ the actual Fréchet derivative of $I$ at $x$: $$dI(x)(u) = \left(v, u\right)$$

Comment: This answer might help you clear things up about Fréchet derivatives: [Frechet derivative chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up my comments above: first, this answer here [Frechet derivative chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217002) should provide sufficient explanation about Fréchet derivatives and the chain rule for our context, so I'll just extract the relevant information.
Given $X$ and $Y$ two normed spaces (usually Banach spaces but they don't have to be) the Fréchet derivative of a function $f : X \to Y$ at a point $x$, which I'll denote by $df(x)$, is defined (when it exists) as the unique bounded linear functional such that:
$$f(a+h)=f(a)+df(x)(h)+\underset{\|h\| \to 0}{o}(\|h\|)$$
And then you can prove the following theorem, called the chain rule:

> Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three normed spaces, $a \in X$, $U$ a neighbourhood of $a$ in $X$ and $V$ a neighbourhood of $f(a)$ in $Y$, and finally $f: U \subset X \to Y$ and $g : V \to Z$ be two functions which are Fréchet-differentiable in neighbourhoods of respectively $a$ and $f(a)$.
> Then, $g \circ f$ is Fréchet-differentiable in a neighbourhood of $a$ in $X$, and:
> $$d(g \circ f)(a) = dg(f(a)) \circ df(a)$$

If we let $U = X = Z := \mathbb{R}$ and $V = Y := H$, and $f := \eta$ and $g := I$, then we are in this exact situation, meaning that we have:
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R},\quad d(I \circ \eta)(t) = dI(\eta(t)) \circ d\eta(t)$$
Now, $\eta$ is a function which starts from $\mathbb{R}$, and so $d\eta$ will always be of the form $h \mapsto h w$ for some unique vector $w \in H$, thus it is customary to define $\eta'(t) := w$.
Similarly, $d(I \circ \eta)(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{r}$ is of the form $d(I \circ \eta)(t) : h \mapsto (I \circ \eta)'(t) h$, this time $(I \circ \eta)'(t)$ is the standard notion of derivative on the reals and $\cdot$ is the usual scalar multiplication.
Moreover, $dI(x) : H \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded linear functional, thus by the Riesz representation theorem there exists a unique vector $v \in H$ such that:
$$\forall u \in H,\quad dI(x)(u) = (v, u)$$
I'm assuming that $v$ is thus the vector you called $I'(x)$.

Putting these notations in the chain rule and evaluating at $h \in \mathbb{R}$, we obtain:
$$\begin{split}
\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \forall h \in \mathbb{R},\quad (I \circ \eta)'(t) \cdot h &= d(I \circ \eta)(t)(h)\\
&= dI(\eta(t))(d\eta(t)(h))\\
&= dI(\eta(t))(\eta'(t) h)\\
&= \Big(I'(\eta(t)), \eta'(t) h\Big)\\
&= \Big(I'(\eta(t)), \eta'(t) \Big) \cdot h
\end{split}$$
Hence, taking $h = 1$:
$$(I \circ \eta)'(t) = \Big(I'(\eta(t)), \eta'(t) \Big)$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: No problem, glad to have been of help.